# How many ways to skip first record from a file using bcp

Tags: batch-processing

my file format is .xx1 when i try to exclude the first recording using -F 2 ,it pick from 3rd line instead of 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
bulk insert <table> from '<path of data file>'

with

(

firstrow=2,

formatfile='<path of formatfile>'

)
```

Comment: @user1686102:- You can prepare a batch file to delete the first row from the file and then use the -F option to fetch records. Will that be OK(I will update my answer if you want)

Comment: This has nothing to do with batch files. `Batch files are text-based scripts that are executed by the command processor (typically COMMAND.COM on DOS and earlier versions of Windows, cmd.exe on OS/2 and later version of Windows).`